# Having trouble translating english to FOL

Tags: predicate-logic

Having trouble with this phrase: Any column that contains a cube contains a tetrahedron, and vice versa.

I tried this:
∀x ∀y ((Cube(x) ∧ Tet(y)) → SameCol(x, y))

which is incorrect because this says that every cube and tet has to be in the same single column. I'm having trouble with saying "any" column.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your model allow you to quantify over columns? It feels like you’re missing a variable !

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Every column that contains a cube contains a tetrahedron."

So: "For *every* cube there is *some* tetrahedron that is in the same column."

Comment: This might work for the questioner’s needs, but flipping the quantifiers can have unexpected consequences depending on the model. For example, if there are cubes that (for whatever reason) are not in columns, it then becomes an open question as to whether there is a tetrahedron in “the same column”. A counter example of an uncolumned cube with no associated tetrahedron existence conditions would falsify your statement, but not the original.